# O que é Big data e qual sua relação com o modelo relacional?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, big-data

Estava lendo sobre [big data](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data), no entanto ainda não consegui compreender o que de fato seria o big data em sua essência. Sempre utilizei o modelo RDBMS para armazenamento e manipulação de dados e neste ponto também me surgem duvidas ligadas ao big data.

## Dúvidas

1. O que é big data?
2. Qual a relação que o big data tem com os bancos de dados
   relacionais?

Answer (score 2):

Big data é um conceito que se tem falado muito nos últimos anos.

Em 2000, Doug Laney definiu este conceito com 3 V's:

- **Volume** - Necessidade de armazenar uma grande quantidade de dados
- **Velocidade** - Necessidade de obter esses dados de forma rápida e acessível
- **Variedade** - Os dados podem ter múltiplos formatos, desde formatos mais estruturados (tabelas, dados textuais ou numéricos) ou formatos menos estruturados (vídeos, áudios, imagens, documentos de texto).

**Porque é que o Big Data tem sido muito falado nos últimos anos e porque é tão importante?**

- Aumento da produção de dados, nomeadamente, de Big Data. Este aumento tem se refletido com o crescimento da área da Internet das Coisas. Para além disso, cada vez há mais informação a ser partilhada, que variam, desde comportamentos do consumidor, dados de dispositivos eletrónicos.
- Crescente necessidade da utilização de Big Data. Com o passar dos anos, muitos produtos inteligentes têm surgido no mercado. A grande maioria desses produtos inteligentes, utilizam e geram dados para um melhor desempenho global.
- Partilha de dados é partilha de conhecimento. Isto permite às empresas identificar potenciais problemas de uma forma mais rápida o que, consequentemente, reduz custos, otimiza produtos/serviços e tornam o modelo de negócio mais inteligente.
- Crescimento da área da Inteligência Artificial, nomeadamento, de Deep Learning. O Deep Learning é uma técnica com alguns anos, mas só nos últimos anos tem havido uma massificação desta técnica. Porquê? Porque Deep Learning necessita de um enorme conjunto de dados para treinar os seus modelos, o que antigamente era mais complicado de se obter. Com o surgimento de dados em grande quantidade, o Deep Learning obteve uma nova vida e hoje é talvez a principal sub-área da Inteligência Artificial.

**Em que áreas pode ser aplicado o Big Data?**

- **Dados Sociais** - Dados de comportamentos de pessoas. Este tipo de dados vai desde dados de redes sociais, de pesquisas em motores de busca, perfis de pessoas (idade, localização,...)
- **Dados de Negócio** -  Dados gerados por empresas/organizações dos mais variados setores (produção, marketing, recursos humanos, financeiro) e que tem como objetivo mensurar os resultados e identificar potenciais lacunas.
- **Dados Pessoais** -  Estes dados estão ligados a uma área também ela muito popular recentemente, a Internet das Coisas. Estes dados são gerados a partir de produtos inteligentes, nomeadamente produtos que tenham acesso a Internet, e que por norma têm alguns sensores associados. Estes valores podem ser usados em vários fins, dependendo da sua utilidade.